# Commenting about $f'(0)$

Tags: functions, derivatives

If $f$ is a continuous and differentiable function in $\Bbb R$ and $f\big(\frac{1}{n}\big)=0$ for all $n \geq 1$, and $n \in \Bbb Z$, comment about $f'(0)$.

I understand that $f(0)=0$ by taking limit to infinity. But while writing the first principle expression, I am stuck with $\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(h)}{h}$. Please help me how to proceed further.

Comment: Since $f$ is given to be differentiable, i.e. $f'(0)$ exists so all we have to do is compute the limit $\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(h)}{h}$. Since the limit exists so let us ask what if we take $h \to 0$ using the sequence $\{1/n\}$, then $f(h)=0$. so..

Comment: MathJax, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $f'(0)$ exists, we have $f'(0)=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{f(1/n+0)-f(0)}{1/n}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{0-0}{1/n}=\lim_{n\to \infty}0=0$.

Note that I have used the following fact:

For a function $g:D\to \Bbb R$ and $c$ is a limit point of $D$, we say $\lim_{x\to c}g(x)=l$ if and  only if for every sequence $\{x_n\}$ of points of $D\backslash \{c\}$ converging to $c$, the corresponding function sequence $\{f(x_n)\}$ converges to $l$.

Here we have to apply "only if" part to the function $g:\Bbb R\backslash\{0\}\to \Bbb R$ defined by $g(h)=\frac{f(h+0)-f(0)}{h}=\frac{f(h)}{h}$ for $h\not=0$.

Comment: @Riemann'sPointyNose, This is because $f(1/n)=0$ for all natural nos. $n$

Comment: What is the limit of the sequence whose each term is $0$.

Comment: Ohhhhhh right yeah sorry, ignore me haha

Comment: @Riemann'sPointyNose, I also had this doubt so I commented but then I saw the question again and realized what went wrong 

Comment: Yeah aha, I forgot what the question was lol

Answer (score 2):

A crucial step is to establish

$$f(0)=0.$$ But this is easy by continuity of $f$,

$$f\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\right)=f(0)=f\left(\frac1n\right)=0.$$

Finally,

$$f'(0)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}h=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(h)}h=\lim_{n\to\infty}nf\left(\frac1n\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}0=0.$$